# Where is the problem with this if else statement and print?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make sense of this test exercise I am working on.
I wrote the below code and it gets executed, however, the result is not what I actually wanted.
The first if statements supposed to print either day or days depending on how many days passed.
The last print, solution, supposed to print the days plus the text with a space between, however, I cannot make this happen.
Thanks in advance!

```
well_height = 125
daily_distance = 30
nightly_distance = 20
snail_position = 0
notEscaped = True

# Create a variable days to keep
# count of the days that pass until the snail escapes the well

days = 0

fullDaylydist = daily_distance - nightly_distance

while snail_position < well_height:
    if days <= 1:
        print(str(days) + " day gone")
    else:
        print(str(days) + " days gone")
    snail_position += fullDaylydist
    if snail_position < well_height:
        days += 1
# Print the solution.
    else:
        print(str(days) + " days and I am out from the well!")
```

Comment: can you give us an expected input and output (what you would see in the terminal?)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems that I was trying to print another file and it confused me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is that the snail moves forward during the day and backward at night. The snail will reach the top during the day *before* sleeping.

```
well_height = 125
daily_distance = 30
nightly_distance = 20
snail_position = 0
notEscaped = True

days = 1
snail_position = 0

fullDaylydist = daily_distance - nightly_distance  # assumes full day

while snail_position < well_height - daily_distance:  # check if snail reaches top during day
    if days <= 1:
        print(str(days) + " day gone")
    else:
        print(str(days) + " days gone")
    snail_position += fullDaylydist
    if snail_position < well_height:
        days += 1
# Loop done, Print the solution.
print(str(days) + " days and I am out from the well!")  # last day
```

Output

```
1 day gone
2 days gone
3 days gone
4 days gone
5 days gone
6 days gone
7 days gone
8 days gone
9 days gone
10 days gone
11 days and I am out from the well!
```

Answer (score 0):

The first if is days less than or equal to one.  Do you mean this or should it say greater than or equal to one which would be >=

Comment: hey! Thanks, but it turned out that it worked after all.